# Fixed scrolling scale with window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I have an ecommerce website, I'm attempting to make my product page looking like [this](https://www.aloyoga.com/w4260r-reflective-idol-bomber-jacket). However the problem I'm running into is that the script only works if nothing moves around or changes. As soon as the window size is changed all the initial fixed point in the script that tells it where to stop gets all messed up.

I added a location.reload() function but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {

    var isMobile = false;

    if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) isMobile = true;


    if(isMobile == false){
        var myElem = document.getElementById('details');
        if(myElem == null){
            exit();
        }

        var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        if(windowWidth != jQuery(window).width()){
            console.log("test");
            location.reload();
        }
        });


        var elementPosition = jQuery('#details').offset();

        var reviews = jQuery('#customer-reviews').offset();

        var pos = reviews.top;

        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > (elementPosition.top)){

                jQuery('#details').css('position','fixed').css('top','70px').css('right','0');
                if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > pos - 500){                 //-900
                    jQuery('#details').css('position', 'absolute').css('top', pos - 700).css('right','0');
                }
            } else {
                jQuery('#details').css('position','static');
            }
        })

    }

})
```

So how do I get all my variables to refresh when the page size is changed?

Comment: use css @media tag to adjust the screen like in [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) also try bootstrap....

Comment: rather than using the `px` values in styles, using %age would help!

Comment: @PrashanthBenny I don't think that would work? That will only apply to fixed sizes, if the user manually change the size of their browser then who knows how big it'll be. Also, what does %age do?

Comment: %age adjusts dynamically to the screen size...

Comment: bootstrap is also designed to adjust according to the changing sizes instantaneously